# Desenhar um ponto em uma imagem com base em suas coordenadas ao clicar sobre ela

Tags: javascript, css

Meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho gerar um ponto que fiz em CSS em uma imagem que chamo no meu JS, porém, ela deve ser gerada nas coordenadas que são capturadas ao clicar sobre a imagem.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function coordenadas(event){
            x = event.clientX;
            y = event.clientY;
            //alert("X: "+x+" Y: "+y);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function image() {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 1) + 1);
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "../radiografias/"+x+".jpg";
            document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img style=\"cursor:crosshair\" href=\"#\" onmousedown= \"coordenadas(event)\" src=\""
                + img.src + "\" width=1100 />";
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        .ponto{
            width: 5px;
            height: 5px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #FFFF00;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="image"></div>
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço muito...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer isso criando o elemento dentro da `div`:

```js
function coordenadas(event){
   x = event.clientX;
   y = event.clientY;
   //console.log("X: "+x+" Y: "+y);
   
   var pto = document.querySelector('#image .ponto');
   
   if(pto !== null) pto.outerHTML = ''; // apago o ponto anterior, se houver
   
   var div = document.getElementById('image');
   var ponto = document.createElement("span");
   ponto.className = "ponto";
   ponto.style.cssText = "top: "+(parseInt(y)-2.5)+"px; left: "+(parseInt(x)-2.5)+"px;";
   div.appendChild(ponto); // crio o ponto
}

function image() {
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 1) + 1);
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg";
   document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "<img style=\"cursor:crosshair\" href=\"#\" onmousedown= \"coordenadas(event)\" src=\""
       + img.src + "\" width=1100 />";
}
image();
```

```css
.ponto{
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #FFFF00;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Show cara, muito obrigado mesmo. Porém, não sei por qual motivo ele não está criando o ponto no local onde clico, ele acaba criando o ponto a uma certa distância. Tipo, executando o código aqui, ele realmente funciona, porém quando eu executo ele em minha página, fica dando esse "erro".

Comment: Acho que o erro é pq estou obtendo as coordenadas da tela e não da imagem em si...

Comment: E tbm estou trabalhando com uma página em PHP

Comment: Creio que a solução para isso é capturar as coordenadas da minha div onde fica a minha imagem, porém, ainda não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Vc pode ver meu código completo aqui: https://github.com/argalvao/Projeto_Odonto

Comment: Aqui está: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13_BleNp5J_VEuDQb72u9oCfSw3MgzzL7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Desculpa a demora pra responder...

Comment: Conseguiu analisar o código?

Comment: Tem alguma ideia de como fazer funcionar?

Comment: sim, estou vendo...

Comment: Velho...muito obrigado mesmo. Realmente funcionou. Você me ajudou bastante!!

Comment: Tranquilo!.....